# Is this normal behavior when connecting to remote database that is located on shared hosting?

Tags: sql-server, security, shared-hosting

So I have a shared hosting for ASP.NET MVC3 and I just created a new database on Plesk.

Next I wanted to connect to database remotely using Sql Manager and I entered server name, username and password.

Everything fine so far but after I clicked on Database Name, it gave me a list of all sort of databases I never heard of.I guess those are databases of other people.

I am wondering is this normal behavior?

Comment: Sometimes hosts will let you see everyone else's databases but won't let you query them. If they do, get a new host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions to *hide* database you don't have permissions in have side effects

So you can usually see the databases but you should have *no* rights at all to see any data in them, even system data. That is, there should be no login-user mapping

Comment: Which is why hosting services shouldn't use identifiable names for databases.

Comment: Yes, you can see other database, but I believe you cant access other databases as you dont have the rights. :)